# How to set a match path in security rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

[image]I am trying to learn how to use security rules but it is not working
I actually wrote two rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /users/{user} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

First one is working perfectly but the second one is not although I have a collection called users

Comment: Rules on themselves do nothing until you execute code against them. Can you edit your question to show that minimal code that doesn't give the results you expected against the match on `/users`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have Updated  the image

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to write to the path `documents/users` in the database, which creates a document called `users` in the `documents` collection. Your security rules only allow writing to the `users` collection, so more like you'll want to write to `users/myuid` in the playground.